# How to retrieve Multi Value Lookup List REST Api Sharepint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api

have 2 lists,
I tried to retrieve the values ​​of lookup field (one or more values ​​from the Finance list (Title, Country (lookup field to the list Country column "Title"

```
$("#Finance").autocomplete({

    minLength: 2,

    source: function(request, response) {

        var term = request.term;

        var restUrl = "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Finance')/items?$select=Title,Pays/Country&$expand=Country/Title&$filter=substringof('" + term + "',Title)";
        $.ajax({

            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",

            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },

            url: restUrl,

            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                console.log("beforeSend");
            },
            success: function(data) {

                response($.map(data.d.results, function(value, key) {


                    return {
                        label: value.Title,
                        value: value.Title,
                        country: value.Country,
                        value: value.Country

                    };

                }));

            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Erreur');
            },
            complete: function() {
                console.log("complete");
            }
        });

    },

    // Run this when the item is in focused (not selected)
    focus: function(event, ui) {

        return false;
    },
    // Run this when the item is selected
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#Country").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#Finance").val(ui.item.Country);
        return false;
    },
});

});
```

the result is [object] [object], [object] [object]

Comment: Are you sure about your list Title ? Fiance or Finance, Verify the restUrl

Comment: there is no problem, just typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t understand what "`$select=Title,Pays/Country&$expand=Country/Title`" means.

In general, we use `$select=Title,LookupField/Id,LookupField/Title,LookupField/CustomField&$expand=LookupField`

You need to get lookup value in `success` function, 
e.g.

```
return {
    label: value.Title,
    value: value.Title,
    country: value.Country.Title,
    value: value.Country.Title    
};
```

**Here is my testing :**

my lists:

[image]

Use the following scripts in the page:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
$( function() {
    $("#Finance").autocomplete({

        minLength: 2,

        source: function(request, response) {

            var term = request.term;

            var restUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Finance')/items?$select=Title,Country/Title,Country/ID&$expand=Country&$filter=substringof('" + term + "',Title)";
            $.ajax({

                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",

                headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },

                url: restUrl,

                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log("beforeSend");
                },
                success: function(data) {

                    response($.map(data.d.results, function(value, key) {


                        return {
                            label: value.Title,
                            value: value.Title,
                            country: value.Country.Title,
                            value: value.Country.Title

                        };

                    }));

                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('Erreur');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    console.log("complete");
                }
            });

        },

        // Run this when the item is in focused (not selected)
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
        },
        // Run this when the item is selected
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#Finance").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#Country").val(ui.item.country);
            return false;
        },
    });

});
  </script>


<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <label for="Finance">Finance: </label>
  <input id="Finance">
</td>
<td><input id="Country"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**The testing results:**

[image]

Selected "JavaScript":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Multi valued lookups come back as arrays, so you need to process them as such.